# Field addition based on drop down option selection in java

Tags: javascript, java, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdown` list field in my server pages. I want to add text fields to the page depending on the option chosen in the drop down.

The java code where the fields are rendered :

```
protected void printContent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        makeJsScriptsAdvancedRest(request, sb);

        sb.append("<TABLE id='abc' style='width:100%;'> \n");
            makePagingTypeField(sb);
        sb.append("</TABLE>");
        if (option 1 : don't show fields)
        {
            sb.append("<TABLE id='certs1' style='display:none'>");
            makeField1(sb);
            sb.append("</TABLE>");
            sb.append("<TABLE id='certs2' style='display:none'>");
            makeField2(sb);
            makeField3(sb);
            makeField4(sb);
            sb.append("</TABLE>");
        }
        else if (option 2 : show fields in certs1)
        {
            sb.append("<TABLE id='certs1' style='display:block'>");
            makeField1(sb);
            sb.append("</TABLE>");
            sb.append("<TABLE id='certs2' style='display:none'>");
            makeField2(sb);
            makeField3(sb);
            makeField4(sb);
            sb.append("</TABLE>");
        }
        else if (option 3 : show fields in certs2)
        {
            sb.append("<TABLE id='certs1' style='display:none'>");
            makeField1(sb);
            sb.append("</TABLE>");
            sb.append("<TABLE id='certs2' style='display:block'>");
            makeField2(sb);
            makeField3(sb);
            makeField4(sb);
            sb.append("</TABLE>");
        }
        print(sb, true);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

According to the answer by *drgPP*, I changed the code as follows.
Javascript code :

The `FLD_PagingType` is name of the PaginField drop down list.

```
protected void makeJsScriptsAdvancedRest(HttpServletRequest request,StringBuffer sb)    {
    sb.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n");
    sb.append("function updateValues() {\n");
    sb.append(" var y = document.getElementById('certs1'); var z = document.getElementById('certs2');"+

            " var x = document.getElementById('" + FLD_PagingType + "'); var w = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;" +

            "if(w =='" + PAGE_BASED + "') { y.style.display = 'block'; z.style.display = 'none'; }" +

            "else if(w =='" + RECORD_BASED + "') { y.style.display = 'none'; z.style.display = 'block';}  " +

            "else if(w =='" + NO_PAGINATION + "') { y.style.display = 'none'; z.style.display = 'none';} \n");

    sb.append("}\n");
    sb.append("</script>\n");
}
```

The `getSelectValue()` returns the string option value.

I can operate the select field properly but onthing changes on UI when options are chosen.

Any suggestions,pointers are appreciated!

Comment: I really didn't understood your question/problem.

Comment: I want the functionality of adding different set of fields on UI depending on selected option. But with the above code even after the change in select field, there is no field attached to the UI

Comment: is the problem in javascript or the java code? Can you edit the question to be [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.html) - creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the problem would help

Comment: @Mousey I did not know where the error was,that's why I posted here. But now I know that the error was in javascript. I edited the code of javascript

Comment: @Vaishnavee will edit the wiki for the debugging tag with some resources for debugging -  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/debugging/info - Popular questions in the debugging tag is useful too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in javascript, to test equality you must use `==` (to test values) or `===` (to test values and types), but NOT `equals()` method (this is a java method).

You have mentioned in tags `jQuery` and you have used `JavaScript`.

Example how to use jQuery to add listener on `<select></select>` events.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="field" name="field" type="text" value="" />
<select id="test" name="test">
 <option value="1">First value</option>
 <option value="2">Second value</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").change(function() {
       var selectedValue = $("#test").val();
       if (selectedValue == "1") {
          $("#field").val("First option selected");
       } else {
          $("#field").val("Second option selected");
       }
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

P.S: Don't forget to import jQuery library before you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am just a beginner in Java-script and was not sure about the use of jQuery in my context. If I have to stick to javaScript (w/o importing the jQuery lib) can I do this?

Comment: @Vaishnavee yes, jQuery is just a library build on the base of JavaScript to make the syntax easier and providing a lot of useful functions. I think the comparison of the fields using `==` should resolve your problem. But you must bind the [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event to your select tag.

Comment: Yes I am setting `setOnChange("updateValues();")` for the drop down list. I will try out with the `==` comparison.

Comment: That worked partially correct,now the fields are attached and they change - case 2 and 3 in java code `printContent()` but in option 1 I want to hide the fields. But the attached fields are not disappearing.

Comment: @Vaishnavee you must be sure that value of the variable `NO_PAGINATION` is the same (take care of empty spaces and upper-lower cases) as the **TEXT** (be aware you are extracting the option's text, not value) you are selecting from `<select>` tag which is responsible for hiding the tables.

Comment: My mistake, i was not ignoring the case of text. I was stuck on this issue for quite a while, thanks a bunch!! :) Now the whole thing works perfectly